# Angularjs undefined object when attribute two-way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am running into a problem with something I'm trying to do in AngularJS.
The thing goes like this:

I have a controller and I have a directive defined like this:

```
helpers.directive('someEvent', function() {

    ...
    scope: {
       api: '='
    }
    ...
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.hasSomeEventOccured = function(){

            return booleanVariable
        };

        $scope.api = {
           hasSomeEventOccured: $scope.hasSomeEventOccured
       }
    }]

});
```

Then, in some other controller I want to access that function `hasSomeEventOccured`... 
the controller is defined as follows:

```
moduleName.controller('moduleSomethingController',
['$scope', '$state', 'moduleRepository', function ($scope, $state, moduleRepository) {

    $scope.theEventOccured = $scope.someEventApi.hasSomeEventOccured();

}]);
```

And in the cshtml file I have:

```
<some-event api="someEventApi" ></some-event>

<div ng-if="theEventOccured"></div>
```

**The error that occasionally occurs is that `$scope.someEventApi` is undefined.**
And so this line breaks: **`$scope.theEventOccured = $scope.someEventApi.hasSomeEventOccured();`**
I assume this happens because the call to `hasSomeEventOccured` within the `moduleSomethingController` occurs before the binding with `someEvent` is completed.

My question is how do you solve this problem?

I am aware that in a directive you would have something like:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   attrs.$observe(...);
}
```

But how can I achieve something like wait for the binding to complete in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

SO- The reason you get "$scope.someEventApi is undefined" error, is because you didn't set it anywhere. it is undefined! Everything you use inside the controller should be either defined (var x = something...) or injected (just like you injected $scope in your example)

The way i see it, you have two options to get what you want:

1. a common and straightforward way will be to define your function inside **the controller** and then **send that function** to the directive. that means you'll need to add your directive definition something like that:

`scope: {theEventOccured: '&' }`

the & sign means it's a function.

inside your controller:

```
$scope.theEventOccured = function() { /* your code here */ }
```

this way- the API is actually defined inside your controller, and the directive uses it when needed.

1. for more complex stuff- you can create a .factory and bind it to your controller and directive.
2. if you are trying to communicate between different controllers (or controllers of directive) you can either use a factory or $broadcast an event. see $broadcast and $emit in [the scope api](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

two other important things:
usually you are not supposed to use a directive's function in it's parent controller scope
if i understand what you want to achieve, you do not need $observe here.